# Stored procedure to modify bit flag, can't use Enums since many apps will be modifying it, what should I do?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, bit-manipulation

There is a column in a database that is of type INT (Sql server).

This int value is used at a bit flag, so I will be AND'ing and OR'ing on it.

I have to pass a parameter into my sproc, and that parameter will represent a specific flag item.

**I would normally use an enumeration and pass the int representation to the sproc**, but since many different modules will be accessing it it won't be practicial for them all to have my enum definition (if it is changed, it will be a headache to roll it out).

So should I use a 'string' or a magic-number as the parameter value, then in my sproc I will do:

```
IF(@blah = 'approved')
BEGIN
      // bit banging here
END
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a string, and a CASE construct:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE BitBang(@Flag AS VARCHAR(50), @Id AS INT)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @Bit INT

  SET @BIT = CASE @Flag
    WHEN 'approved'   THEN 16
    WHEN 'noapproved' THEN 16
    WHEN 'fooflag'    THEN 8
    WHEN 'nofooflag'  THEN 8
  END

  IF @Bit IS NOT NULL
  BEGIN
    IF LEFT(@Flag, 2) = 'no' 
    BEGIN
      UPDATE TheTable SET BitField = BitField & ~@Bit WHERE Id = @Id
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
      UPDATE TheTable SET BitField = BitField | @Bit WHERE Id = @Id
    END
  END
END
```

Comment: what is this doing: IF LEFT(@Flag, 2) = 'no'   Just to make sure the person didn't put in a trailing space?

Comment: I assumed you wanted a way to *un*set a bit, too. One way to express this would be using a "[flag]" vs. "no[flag]" argument. This line checks if the flag should be set or if it should be unset. You could also do it by passing an additional parameter (for example, a BIT).

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the old 0 and 1 for the flag? It is widely accepted as a bit switch already and there would be no confusion or misspelling as to what 0 and 1 mean.  Unless you are saying that there will be more than 2 flags and that more than 1 flag will have the same ultimate meaning

Comment: i would then use the actual int values. using a string as a flag is just asking for trouble IMO.